# Instagram log-in not work

Tags: instagram-api

I try to log-in via instagram, but instead i get this error. I can't find solution for this, so please help me to solve this. I get this error when try to send request like this:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token



{"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Invalid application ID.","type":"OAuthException","code":101,"fbtrace_id":"HBZxDDhSbzu"}}
```